# Using "and" with "in"

Tags: mysql, sql

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE colors 
    (
     image_id int, 
     color char(6)
    );

INSERT INTO colors
(image_id, color)
VALUES
(1, '22ffcc'),
(2, '22ffcc'),
(2, '2200cc'),
(3, '22ffcc');
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9243/2)

I want to fetch only those image_id where image id is any among (`2,3`) but only that image_id which have both colors `'22ffcc' and '2200cc'` against that image id

In given example my desired result is `2`

But it is giving me `2,2,3`

Can we use `and` with `in` somehow?... As By default it uses `or`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical solution for your problem is to count the distinct values of colors for every image_id:

```
select image_id
from colors where color in ( '22ffcc' , '2200cc' )
and image_id in (2,3)
GROUP BY image_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT color) = 2;
```

Explanation:
To have both colors, the number of counts must be the same as the values in the value list of IN.
You can check the results of aggregate functions with the `HAVING` clause not with `WHERE`

see [modified fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9243/5)

Comment: Yes. Seems what i need. Thanks for explaination

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for specific colors that appear on different rows, then you can join the table on itself:

```
select color1.image_id
from colors color1
join colors color2 on color1.image_id = color2.image_id
where color1.color = '22ffcc' and color2.color = '2200cc'
and color1.image_id in (2,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

`IN` only works on a single row, it cares not a jot for the other rows in the table.

`x IN (1,2,3)` is basically short hand for `x=1 OR x=2 OR x=3` and saves a huge amount of syntactical mess when using `IN (SELECT ... )`.

Asking for an `AND` version of `IN` is nonsensical as presumably `ANDIN(1,2,3)` would be short for `x=1 AND x=2 AND x=3` which would always return `false` for a row.

For a solution to your specific problem, see the other answers.